# SearchView no filtra texto de busqueda

Tags: kotlin, recyclerview, searchview

Tengo un searchView al que le ingreso un texto para buscar la palabra ingresada a través de un modelo el cual tiene un campo llamado descripción y dicho modelo se carga en un recyclerview. Pretendo que al encontrar el dato con la información se almacene en otro modelo llamado encontrado para limpiar el recyclerview y mostrar los modelos (encontrado) con la información de los que contengan la palabra a buscar (ingresada en el searchview) pero solamente me carga el modelo con toda la información y la búsqueda no me funciona. Este es mi codigo

fragment_listalimentos.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".fragmentosUsuario.ListalimentosFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/txtBuscarali"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:queryHint="Buscar por nombre"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/listalimentos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".9" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

ListaalimentosFragment

```
class ListalimentosFragment: Fragment(), AdapterListaComida.ClickListener, SearchView.OnQueryTextListener,
    AdapterEncontrado.ClickListener {

    private val lista: ArrayList<Alimento> = ArrayList()
    private val listaenc: ArrayList<Alimento> = ArrayList()
    private lateinit var encontrado: ArrayAdapter<Alimento>
    private lateinit var database: FirebaseDatabase
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private var user = ""     // id de usuario de firebase

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        val rv = binding.listalimentos
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true)
        rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        encontrado = ArrayAdapter(requireActivity(), R.layout.row_encontrado,lista)
        binding.txtBuscarali.isFocused
        binding.txtBuscarali.setOnQueryTextListener(object:     androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                binding.txtBuscarali.clearFocus()
                if (lista.contains(Alimento(query))){
                    encontrado.filter.filter(query)
                }
                return false
            }

            @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                //filtrado(newText.toString())
                encontrado.filter.filter(newText)
                return true
            }

        })
   }    
}
```

row_encontrado.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:contentPaddingTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/fotoenc"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tituloenc"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded,SpUsage,UseCompatTextViewDrawableXml"
                    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_add_list"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

AdapterListaComida

```
class AdapterListaComida (internal var context: Context, internal var itemList:ArrayList<Comidadia>,
                          val clic: ClickListener
):
    RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterListaComida.VistaHolder>(){

    class VistaHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val des: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvcomidadia)
        val pro: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvprod)
        val car: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvcald)
        val gra: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvgrasad)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): VistaHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_comidadia,parent,false)
        return VistaHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: VistaHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.des.text = itemList[position].descripcion
        holder.pro.text = itemList[position].proteinas
        holder.car.text = itemList[position].carbohidratos
        holder.gra.text = itemList[position].grasas
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{
            clic.onItemClick(itemList[position])
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return itemList.size
    }

    interface ClickListener{
        fun onItemClick(diario: Comidadia)
    }

}
```

AdapterEncontrado

```
class AdapterEncontrado(internal var context: Context, internal var itemList:ArrayList<Alimento>,
                        val clic: ClickListener):
        RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterEncontrado.VistaHolder>(){

    class VistaHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val nombre: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tituloenc)
        val imagen: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fotoenc)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): VistaHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_encontrado,parent,false)
        return VistaHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: VistaHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.nombre.text = itemList[position].descripcion
        val foto = Uri.parse(itemList[position].ruta.toString())
        Picasso.get().load(foto).into(holder.imagen)
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{
            clic.onItemClick(itemList[position])
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return itemList.size
    }

    interface ClickListener{
        fun onItemClick(encontrado: Alimento)
    }

}
```

Me gustaría saber en que puedo estar fallando o donde me estaré equivocando para que no me haga la búsqueda o se asigne al momento de encontrar lo que quiero buscar al modelo que quiero mandar la información. Gracias por la ayuda.